# Problem with pit mutation: "Replaced long addition with subtraction"

Tags: java, testing, junit, mutation-testing, pittesting

I'm newbie with mutation testing. I'm using Pit and in the following line of code there are 4 mutations of the same type: Replaced long addition with subtraction
`long newsize = position + START_OF_DATA + total;`
But I can't figured out why he gaves me 4 mutations and not 3:

```
1 mutation:long newsize = position - START_OF_DATA + total;
2 mutation:long newsize = position + START_OF_DATA - total;
3 mutation:long newsize = position - START_OF_DATA - total;
4 mutation: ???
```

This is the context of the line:

```java
try {
    fc.position(position + START_OF_DATA);
    while (buffs[buffs.length - 1].remaining() > 0) {
        long rc = fc.write(buffs);
        if (rc <= 0) {
            throw new IOException("Short write");
        }
        total += rc;
    }
} finally {
    fc.force(true);
    long newsize = position + START_OF_DATA + total;
    if (newsize > size) {
        size = newsize;
    }
}
```

I've also tried to manually modify the source code with this three supposed mutation and my test suite failed.
Which one could be the fourth mutation? Is there a way to see in clear the mutations and not just the list with the original code reported in the pit report?

Thanks to all

Comment: How about adding parenthesis? Addition and subtraction are evaluated from left to right. With parenthesis you could force an evaluation from right to left.

Comment: Because of the commutativity of addition, there shouldn't be any difference. But with subtraction, you might arrive at different results considering edge cases.

Comment: I've tried `long newsize = position - (START_OF_DATA + total);` but it seems like `long newsize = position - START_OF_DATA - total;` anyway my test suite falied :(

Comment: Can you show the line of code in context? Is it in a finally block?

Comment: I've added the line context...yes, my line is in a finally block, is that the reason of my problem?